# ODBC connection through dsn error

Tags: python, sql, odbc, pyodbc

I have an issue trying to call my uid and password through pyodbc.connect

Here is my odbc.ini:

```
[my_dsn]
Driver= SQL Server
Server=my_server
User=uid_reader
Password=password_reader
MultiSubnetFailover=Yes
Database=master
```

When I hard code, it works perfectly and I can connect

```
test_uid = 'uid_reader'
test_password = 'password_reader'

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=my_dsn;UID={a};PWD={b}'.format(a=test_uid,b=test_password))
```

When I call my dsn variables from my odbc.ini, it doesn't work

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=my_dsn;UID=User;PWD=Password')
```

> Error: ('28000', "[28000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'User'. (18456)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

I would like to hide the password in my odbc.ini so it doesn't appear when I call pyodbc.connect

Comment: The error message shows that `User` is being used as the value for UID. What happens if you do not specify the user and password in the connect string?

Comment: I runned conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=my_dsn'')
and it returns 
Error: ('28000', "[28000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: How are you loading your config? The line `conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=my_dsn;UID=User;PWD=Password')` seems like it's supposed to use the literal string value of `my_dsn`, `User` and `Password`.  My understanding is you should be doing string formatting like you did in your hardcode version, but instead of pointing to the variable, point it to the loaded config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=my_dsn;UID=User;PWD=Password')` seems to be using the literal string values of `my_dsn`, `User` and `Password`.  You can try using keywords [like the documentation here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect), or do a similar string formatting as you did for your hard coded solution but replace it with the loaded config data.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows#using-a-dsn) it seems you *should* be able to load the DSN info directly from the ini, but I haven't had much success on my own either.  The caveat is the document only said you can *possibly* use the login credential, so maybe it depends on the driver?

Either way, below is a version using `configparser` that should work.  It might be considered a hack for some.

```
import pyodbc
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(configfile)   # your odbc.ini file path and name
dsn = config['my_dsn']

#If you want to use Keywords:

conn = connect(driver=dsn['driver'], server=dsn['server'], database=dsn['database'], uid=dsn['user'], pwd=dsn['password'])

#If you want to use string formatting with list comprehension instead:
conn = pyodbc.connect(''.join(['{0}={1}; '.format(k, l) for k, l in d.items()])
```

Comment: A little hack, but it still works and hide the password. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows#using-a-dsn

You can connect to your SQL Server instance using a trusted connection, i.e. using your Windows account rather than a login name and password, by using the Trusted_Connection attribute

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=mynewdsn;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```